# Playing PL Omaha

Tags: rules, rush-poker, omaha, reading-hands

The 5 cards on deck were - 6⋄ T♣ 6♠ K⋄ 4♠

I held a 6 and a king in my deck resulting in a full house hand.

Bet all in, and lost to these opponents cards: T♥ T⋄ 9♣ 2⋄

How did my opponent beat my full house ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

He has TTT66, you have 666KK.

A full house tens full of sixes (TTT66) beats sixes full of kings (666KK) in all variants of poker, not just PLO.  This is because the tens are higher than the sixes, in this case.

Comment: Ahhh, thankyou - the three of a kind was higher than mine, my Kings don't count above his tens because they were only a pair - the highest three of a kind in a full house wins then?! Thankyou - My kings don't count much in this case (don't beat his sixes) - it's only Tens vs 6's.

Comment: Yes, the highest three of a kind would win out.  It's also possible that they would be the same, in which case the winner would be decided by who has the higher pair.  Something like AAA22 vs AAA33, AAA33 would win.